# symfony 4, controller, twig relationship

Tags: symfony, controller, twig

I have built a framework from scratch using the following article series: http://symfony.com/doc/current/create_framework/index.html

Now I have downloaded twig and got templates for it and got these working

```
$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('../templates');
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);
```

But I'm having trouble to using this in controllers with the render method...

How to make twig available in my controllers? 
Do I need to download new components or?

At moment i have the following components required.

```
"symfony/http-foundation": "^4.0",
"symfony/http-kernel": "^4.0",
"symfony/routing": "^4.0",
"symfony/event-dispatcher": "^4.0",
"symfony/dependency-injection": "^4.0",
"twig/twig": "^2.0"
```

Comment: One approach is to define your controllers are services and then inject the twig service into them.  Starts to get a bit involved as there are a number of details to work out.  Might be easier to switch to the new Symfony 4 framework and see how they do it.  https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup.html You can always back fit their solution into your framework if you want.

Comment: Aah, so not just few lines of code more to inject it to controller. I thought it might be easy n simple...

Comment: It's been awhile since I looks at the tutorial in any depth.  If you have the controller resolver working then it should not be too hard to inject $twig as well.

Comment: $routes->add('homepage', new Route('/', array('_controller' => array(new HomeController(), 'indexAction')))); Inject it here?

Comment: Yep.  new HomeController($twig).  Of course you need to have $twig available when you add your routes and will have to adjust your controller to use it.